# Extract lines between and including 2 patterns

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file with data structured as follows

```
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
2, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7
2, q9, q10,,
2, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7
2, r9, r10,,
1, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7
2, s9, s10,,
...
```

I want to get all the lines starting with 1 and ending with ,, so that I get

```
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
1, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7
2, s9, s10,,
```

and if possible get it like,

```
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, 2, p9, p10,,
1, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, 2, s9, s10,,
```

How can I do this with sed or awk?

Comment: Edited to show a more accurate picture of data set. In my  initial question the data was too ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `sed` solution that will string together any sequence of the `,,$` lines following the last occurring `^1` line:

```
sed -e '/^1/{x;s/\n/ /gp;d' -e '};/,,$/H;$G;D
' <<\IN                                                                          
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
2, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7
2, q9, q10,,
2, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7
2, r9, r10,,
1, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7
2, s9, s10,,
IN
```

It e`x`changes `h`old and pattern spaces on lines that begin with a `^1` and `s///p`rints whatever the contents of `h`old space was previous to that only in the event of a successful substitution. Lines ending with `,,$` are appended to `H`old space following a `\n`ewline character and then all lines are `D`eleted up to the first occurring `\n`ewline character. On the `$`last line `H`old space is appended to pattern space following a `\n`ewline - so when it is `D`eleted it restarts the line cycle at the top of the script containing only what `H`old space contained - which gets it printed as necessary.

#### OUTPUT:

```
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7 2, p9, p10,, 2, q9, q10,, 2, r9, r10,,
1, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7 2, s9, s10,,
```

If, on the other hand, you do not want the subsequent `/,,$/` occurrences then this might do:

```
sed -e '/^1/{x;y/\n/ /;s/,,.*/,,/p;d' -e '};/,,$/H;$G;D'
```

Given the same input that prints instead:

```
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7 2, p9, p10,,
1, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7 2, s9, s10,,
```

But that will get `/,,$/` lines printed even if they do not immediately follow a `/^1/` match. If you want the pairs only if they are immediately sequential in input - you can do that as well:

```
sed -n '/^1/!d;$p;N;/\n1/P;/,,$/s/\n/ /p;D'
```

That works thus:

- It first `d`eletes from output all lines which do `!`not begin with `/^1/`

  - This includes lines brought in with `N` that do not end with `/,,$/`.
- If the this is the `$`last input line pattern space is here `p`rinted, because the next command will end the script.
- On `/^1/` matches it appends the `N`ext input line to pattern space following a `\n`ewline character.
- If the appended line *also* begins with a `/\n1/` it `P`rints the previous.

  - `P` prints only up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space.
- After pulling in the `N`ext input line if pattern space `$`ends with a `/,,$/` match it `s///`ubstitutes a space character for the inserted `\n`ewline character and `p`rints the results.
- Pattern space is *always* `D`eleted up to and including the first occurring `\n`ewline character.

  - ...so when a `N`ext input line doesn't match `/,,$/` it is sent back to the top of the script as the head of the line. If at that point it does not match `^1` it is `d`eleted completely.
  - ...because `/,,$/` have already had their `\n`ewline completely removed by this point, they are removed from flow comletely here.

All of this means that if `/^1/` lines follow one another they are still printed, and if lines which do not end in `,,$` follow a `^1` they are not printed.

Comment: sed '/^1/!d;$!N;/\n1/P;//D;/,,$/!s/\n.*//;y/\n/ /' worked perfectly. Thanks. And thanks for all the additional knowledge as well. Will note for future reference

Comment: @jasmaar - please see the edit. I like this better.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first query, you can use `-e` to combine expression in sed:

```
~$ sed -n -e '/^1/p' -e '/,,$/p' f
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
2, p9, p10,,
2, p9, p10,,
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
```

and if you don't want the duplicate:

```
~$ sed -n -e '/^1/p' -e '/,,$/p' f | uniq
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
```

With awk, combine the regex with `;`:

```
~$ awk '/^1/;/,,$/' f
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
2, p9, p10,,
2, p9, p10,,
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7
2, p9, p10,,
```

Comment: You can combine the expressions in `sed` in the same way you can with `awk` - and you can do so portably.

Comment: @fredtantini: Thanks for the assistance. My bad for not providing the proper info upfront.

Answer (score 1):

You may conditionally set `ORS` to get get output in desired format

```
awk '/^1/,/,,$/{ORS = /^1/? ", ": "\n"; print}' file
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, 2, p9, p10,,
1, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, 2, p9, p10,,
```